# Excel VBA - Why aren't Linked Pictures refreshing before copying as image to PPT?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet which uses some raw data to create a colour-coded "dashboard" for several different departments of an organisation. The dashboard itself is created using Linked Pictures of some cells - enabling the dashboard to be conditionally formatted based on cell values. The dashboard displays data for one department at a time, based on whichever department name is entered in a particular cell (which you can change via a drop-down selector).
I have created a macro which iterates through the full list of departments, recalculating the worksheet on each iteration and copy-pasting each department's dashboard into a new slide in a PowerPoint file, as a picture (note - copies this as normal picture, not a linked picture). However, when I run my code, whilst the cell values in the pasted images are correctly updated each time, the Linked Pictures in the dashboard are not being refreshed before the macro copy-pastes a new copy of the dashboard into the PPT.
How can I force Excel to refresh the Linked Pictures on each iteration of the macro loop, so that when it copies and pastes the relevant cells of the worksheet into the PowerPoint, it shows the correct values for each department?

As you will see in my code below... I have tried various fixes, none of which have yet worked. These include each of the following:

```
DoEvents
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Visible = True
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
```

[I've tried to pick out the relevant part of the code for pasting here - but can provide more of the code file, let me know if this would be useful]

```
'Loop through remaining slides, pasting pictures and inputting titles onto each slide
For i = LBound(deptNamesArr) To UBound(deptNamesArr)

    'Set name of dept for results to be obtained and recalculate outputs sheet
    ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("D6").Value = deptNamesArr(i)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Calculate

    If Not Application.CalculationState = xlDone Then
        DoEvents
    End If
    Application.Visible = True

    'Paste two slides per dept - NOTE: first slide is that with the Linked pictures, the second slide is some Excel charts
    For x = 1 To 2
        'Calculate counter for the slide being edited
        i_slide = 1 + ((i - 1) * 2) + x

        'Copy Excel Range
        MyRangeArray(x).Copy

        'Paste to PowerPoint and position
        On Error Resume Next
            Set shp = myPresentation.Slides(i_slide).Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=2) 'Excel 2007-2010
            Set shp = PowerPointApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange 'Excel 2013
        On Error GoTo 0

        'Resize and centre object
        shp.Width = myPresentation.PageSetup.slideWidth * 0.95
        shp.Left = (myPresentation.PageSetup.slideWidth \ 2) - (shp.Width \ 2)
        shp.Top = myPresentation.PageSetup.SlideHeight * 0.2

        'Enter slide title
        myPresentation.Slides(i_slide).Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = deptNamesArr(i) & " " & slideTitleText(x + 1) 'note the "+1" is due to the different way arrays are indexed when read in from cell ranges
    Next x
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    PowerPointApp.Visible = True

    'Paste transfer complete
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ThisWorkbook.Activate
Next i
```

The particular error comes in the first iteration of the loop beginning `For x = 1 To 2` This loop should produce two slides per department - the first (x=1) should copy across the dashboard with the Linked Pictures into a PPT slide, the second (x=2) should copy across a series of four Excel charts into a separate PPT slide. The main loop (indexed by 'i') will then repeat this for each department, appending these slides later into the same PPT file.

Whilst no error message is seen, the dashboard doesn't update fully before it is copied to the PPT - meaning the 'x=1' slides produced are always incorrect. For each department, the first slide for each department (the dashboard) has an updated title (with the dept's name) but doesn't have an updated version of the Linked pictures below it. In contrast, note that the second slide ('x=2') for each department (the Excel charts) always updates fully - and is correct for each department in the Powerpoint slides.